# As of iOS 9, application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: is deprecated, how do I use the new method with iOS 8?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, ios9, uiapplicationdelegate

My current app still supports iOS 8, but I want to move to the new method, `application:openURL:options:`, which isn't available in iOS 8.

How do I support the old method on iOS 8 devices, but the new option on iOS 9 and later?

Comment: You can just implement them both and let the system call whichever one it wants.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is that you can use both methods with same body.
When Application is running in  iOS 8 it will call iOS 8 method otherwise it will call iOS 9 method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with this specific method but can't you do a responds to selector check?

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation)])
{
     // Call the iOS9 Method
}
else
{
    // Call the iOS8 Method
}
```

Comment: No, this is not appropriate here. The question is about delegate methods in `UIApplicationDelegate`. It is the system framework, not the app's code, that will be calling the methods in the question.

Comment: @holex I didn't realise my answer was irrelevant or I wouldn't have posted it, if you guys know everything about 'essential' methods why don't you post an answer. Surely if mine is incorrect so is the answer about the #available block, yet no one is commenting on that post. Thanks for making me feel utterly small and stupid guys. I'll try not to help in future.

Comment: @asjj, you can help in future, but read the question more carefully and try to understand the OP's problem and answer to that – that is not a competition, if you are unsure just leave it, you don't need to present desperately some random answer at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.0 added availability checking with the `#available` block

```
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
    // use new method
} else {
    // use old method
}
```

More info can be found on [this blog post](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking).